# Count unique values in CSV file

Tags: vb.net, csv

I am trying to create a VB (.NET framework) to call a csv and count how many unique values in a column. For example, the csv would look like this:

```
Source Barcode Name,Source ID,Destination Barcode Name,Destination ID
BARCODE_0006,A,Barcode_0001,F
BARCODE_0002,B,Barcode_0001,G
BARCODE_0003,C,Barcode_0001,H
BARCODE_0004,D,Barcode_0001,I
BARCODE_0005,E,Barcode_0001,J
```

The script would return `5` in this example. Note, the number of unique values in column 1 can change.

Comment: There is no such thing as VBScript (.Net Framework) did you mean VB.Net (which is .Net Framework)?

Comment: `TextFieldParser` is a good place to start.

Comment: Yes - that's what I meant. Sorry! I haven't had to use it before (just VBA)

Comment: Hi Catherine. Welcome to StackOverflow.  The idea here is that people will help fix or improve your code, or help you understand how something works.  It is not that people will write your code for you.  So, to improve your question, please attempt something and share the code, and you can explain your thoughts and where you get stuck.

Answer (score 1):

Start with this:

```
Public Iterator Function ReadCSV(filePath As String, Optional delimiter As String = ",") As IEnumerable(Of String())
    Using parser As New TextFieldParser(filePath)
        parser.Delimiters = New String() {delimiter}

        While Not parser.EndOfData
            Yield parser.ReadFields()
        End While
    End Using
End Function
```

And then use it to solve your problem like this:

```
Dim count As Integer = 
    ReadCSV("MyFilePath.csv").  ' Open the file
    Skip(1).                    ' Skip the header
    Select(Function(r) r(0)).   ' Just the first column in each row
    Distinct().                 ' Unique entries only
    Count()                     ' How many there are
```

Comment: This was great and super helpful - I was able to get it to work. Thanks!

Comment: @CatherineH The best way to thank someone on Stack Overflow is to accept their answer by clicking the check mark (tick mark) to the left of the answer. It saves others from attempting to answer the question when the issue is solved. It also helps future readers who are looking for answers to the same question.